# Drupal 8 - Add machine name to block as class programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am looking for a way to add a class to a block, but not a custom class, a class from either the region name or the block machine name.

For example, with regions, this is possible:

```
    {%
       set classes = [ 'region-' ~ region|clean_class]
     %}
```

And every divs would have the name of the region (defined in the info.yml file) as a class. I want to do the same thing with blocks. Either add the name of the region or the machine name as a class. The reason that I want a class is for CSS. It's better practice to target elements usings classes than IDs.

Does anyone know how to achieve that programmatically?

Comment: You cannot add classes to elements with CSS, you have to use Js `document.get***.className = "MyClass"; `

Comment: What framework are you using? Because what you are talking about makes no sense given only the tags you have marked. Also, please look at the tag excerpt when adding tags, since the one for `class` clearly states that `class` is not to be used for CSS classes...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I am on drupal 8.

Answer (score 4):

1) Twig on Drupal 8.x understands only variables and basic operations with variables. So in order to use custom variables (such as the block region) you need to **pass the variables** usually on a **preprocess function** and then use them inside Twig. Here is an example:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook) {
  $block_id = $variables['elements']['#id'];
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);

  // Add region as variable
  $variables['region'] = $block->getRegion();
}
```

and then on **block.html.twig** file:

```
{%
  set classes = ['region-'~region|clean_class]
%}
```

See the docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates.

2) If you want to have custom block template suggestions (eg for a region) you can alter default theme suggestions using [hook_theme_suggestions_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x).

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($variables['elements']['#configuration']['region']) {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
  }
}
```

3) Notice that you are not able to use region specific [Drupal block twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) by default because this functionality removed on 8.x. See related post: https://www.drupal.org/node/2011434.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Comment: I copied what you posted and added the classes like so:

Comment: I copied what you posted and added the classes like so

<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
</div>

But what I get is the function printed on the front page. It doesn"t seem to work. However , I found a module 'block class' which works perfectly. But I would also like to try it your way.

Comment: I also changed  'MYTHEME' with thre name of the theme but to no avail.

Comment: This is not related to the code, you have to study a bit about Twig and/or Drupal. What is the location of the "block.html.twig" file?

Comment: it is in the folder of my custom theme.
custom/layweria/templates/block/block.html.twig

Comment: If you display twig code as plain text on your html then something else is happening. Maybe something is missing from you dev system or a missing <?php tag somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a contributed module such as [block_class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted this too and came across this SO post and OPs Drupal forum post of the same question while looking for an answer. Seeing as I think this answers what we were asking I thought I'd link it here for posterity.

From the [Drupal forum comments](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2016-10-09/add-machine-name-to-block-as-class-programatically) use this snippet by Jeff Burnz in your block twig template:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-' ~ attributes.id,
    'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
    label ? 'block-label-' ~ label|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

This gives you a few options for classes, `attributes.id` is the one I wanted, and if you use just that it outputs

`<div id="blockID" class="block-blockId"...`

I hate styling by ids so will add this to all subthemes I work on from now on. Hope this helps.